# How to post string and get image back from the website

Tags: android

I am new to the android and trying to learn more about android. I am trying to create a app to post the string from the app edit text to the "website(http://vksnr.net/identicon.htm") and get the picture from the website back to my app and display into the ImageView. I already have an edit text, image view and button in my xml file. App should post the string after the button getting clicked and show picture into the ImageView.

Comment: Search how to use `Asynctask` to communicate with your server if the site give you an API to fetch the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web services are incorrect. That website you linked into in your question is effectively a static HTML page with a form element and a dynamically generated image. Your app would have to parse the page, and find the input element and then put your string in there, then after a short delay you would have to read the image thats generated from the form.

However, to make your life easier, if you look at the source of that form, you can see that it is calling gravatar and getting the image from there.

```
<input type="text" name="hash" value="zulnip" onkeyup="this.form.icon.src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=' + MD5(this.form.hash.value) + '&amp;r=PG&amp;s=100&amp;default=identicon'">
```

So, all you really have to do is, MD5 your string in your app, and then get the image in your app (possibly using `ImageView.setImageURI()`). The source of the image will be:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=' + MD5('mystring') + '&amp;r=PG&amp;s=100&amp;default=identicon
```

Comment: It is up to you how you want your app to behave. You can update the image either onkeyup or when the user has finished typing in your textbox and clicks on the button. On a mobile platform (i.e slower internet connections), I would try to avoid the onkeyup approach.

Comment: thank you so much, it works for me, by the way, if i am not using this easy way to do this app, what kind of method or way i should know about to getting the element of this page